# How to get user location

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, cllocationmanager

I'm tracking user location every 1min, here is my code :

LocationService:

```
import CoreLocation
import CoreData

class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationService()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    var timer = Timer()
    var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }
        locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    func startMonitoringLocation() {
        stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func changeLocationAccuracy() {
        switch locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
        case kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation:
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 99999
        case kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers:
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        default: break
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        })

        guard let newLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        let interval = newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

        if abs(interval) > 5 || locationManager.desiredAccuracy != kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation {
            return
        }

        if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
            return
        }

        if currentLocation == nil && newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 70  {
            return
        }

        currentLocation = newLocation

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(LocationService.changeLocationAccuracy), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
         changeLocationAccuracy()
    }
}
```

AppDelegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
        LocationService.shared.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    return true
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    LocationService.shared.startMonitoringLocation()
}
```

The problem is "didUpdateLocations" don't trigger anymore after 20-30mins when I put my app into background. am I missing something?

**Data :**

> ---------- 12:33:41 ---------- accuracy: 100.176340566754, distance: 11.9139937140859 
>   ---------- 12:34:41 ---------- accuracy: 100.178246394771, distance: 32.2963845078517 
>   ---------- 12:35:42 ---------- accuracy: 100.180248268622, distance: 49.5966777976606 
>   ---------- 12:36:42 ---------- accuracy: 100.18076613283, distance: 64.632263503595 
>   ---------- 12:37:42 ---------- accuracy: 200.000181126858, distance: 106.803446309979 
>   ---------- 12:38:42 ---------- accuracy: 100.390802343119, distance: 18.348623950487 
>   ---------- 12:39:43 ---------- accuracy: 150.16852207139, distance: 61.2580288221782 
>   ---------- 12:40:43 ---------- accuracy: 241.375319855098, distance: 146.902117049143 
>   ---------- 12:41:43 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 7.48921464439474 
>   ---------- 12:42:43 ---------- accuracy: 241.000205573651, distance: 146.987877590092 
>   ---------- 12:43:44 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 7.62405179605234 
>   ---------- 12:44:44 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 7.55896269746399 
>   ---------- 12:45:44 ---------- accuracy: 150.000249983526, distance: 38.8944066539055 
>   ---------- 12:46:44 ---------- accuracy: 241.139359617865, distance: 147.142388706418 
>   ---------- 12:47:45 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 41.9643473786135 
>   ---------- 12:48:45 ---------- accuracy: 241.291934833148, distance: 146.675150610266 
>   ---------- 12:49:45 ---------- accuracy: 150.039468172195, distance: 16.6128843089604 
>   ---------- 12:50:45 ---------- accuracy: 150.16560931905, distance: 48.6389862868337 
>   ---------- 12:51:46 ---------- accuracy: 241.07402885546, distance: 147.229614706109 
>   ---------- 12:52:46 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 7.16417432681208 
>   ---------- 12:53:46 ---------- accuracy: 241.06579398531, distance: 146.954120891032 
>   ---------- 12:54:46 ---------- accuracy: 241.062179914206, distance: 147.876920566931 
>   ---------- 12:55:47 ---------- accuracy: 200.04318538883, distance: 38.136053839707 
>   ---------- 12:56:47 ---------- accuracy: 200.180955600876, distance: 88.6844648977498 
>   ---------- 12:57:47 ---------- accuracy: 150.202552895379, distance: 91.8166552231255 
>   ---------- 12:58:47 ---------- accuracy: 65.0, distance: 57.9455407170564 
>   ---------- 12:59:47 ---------- accuracy: 150.166229444757, distance: 34.2036925129397 
>   ---------- 13:00:48 ---------- accuracy: 101.846177093094, distance: 0.407274786609172 
>   ---------- 13:01:48 ---------- accuracy: 102.125798269775, distance: 48.1922586805367 
>   ---------- 13:02:48 ---------- accuracy: 100.180877100619, distance: 16.4299711499485 
>   ---------- 13:03:49 ---------- accuracy: 150.094327388532, distance: 77.2190821337144 
>   ---------- 13:04:49 ---------- accuracy: 241.079810871571, distance: 146.947321088494 
>   ---------- 13:05:49 ---------- accuracy: 241.075270825073, distance: 147.896335551892 
>   ---------- 13:06:49 ---------- accuracy: 100.101061118372, distance: 16.0482204840386 
>   ---------- 13:07:50 ---------- accuracy: 100.091529189521, distance: 5.74914399862917 
>   ---------- 13:08:50 ---------- accuracy: 241.051459353993, distance: 146.942813658832 
>   ---------- 13:09:50 ---------- accuracy: 65.8078917547627, distance: 7.06633659121004 
>   ---------- 13:10:50 ---------- accuracy: 65.8092481623976, distance: 17.3091393420333 
>   ---------- 13:11:51 ---------- accuracy: 244.420168771572, distance: 146.920641901086 
>   ---------- 13:12:51 ---------- accuracy: 241.000779705485, distance: 146.871849682004 
>   ---------- 13:13:51 ---------- accuracy: 241.000203327672, distance: 144.623591144917

Thank's in advance

Comment: How do you test triggering significant location updates for startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges? Maybe you just stopped changing your location significantly?

Comment: When my app is killed i significant location to wake up my app, because i need user location every 1min in every state of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine several problems. But the most probable that you don't get specified accuracy, since

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
```

as I believe don't influence `SignificantLocationChanges` update

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)

> After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update
>   events only when a significant change in the user’s location is
>   detected. It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property
>   to generate events. Calling this method several times in succession
>   does not automatically result in new events being generated. Calling
>   stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() in between, however, does
>   cause a new initial event to be sent the next time you call this
>   method.

From the quote, maybe you try to `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and restart it.

Besides, location update might got sent to your  `didUpdateLocations` method, but could't go through your accuracy checks, for example because given accuracy is lower etc. And your timer method wasn't called as a result.

---

**EDIT**

```
// to start location update properly and register for notifications
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     LocationService.shared.startUpdatingLocation()
     let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
     application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

     return true
}
```

---

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    //.....
    // added local notification to look at the update
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Location: \(currentLocation), task: \(bgTask)"
    notification.fireDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(1.0)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(LocationService.changeLocationAccuracy), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    changeLocationAccuracy()
}
```

That is all that I've changed.

Comment: Can you tell me please what code i need to change in my post ?

Comment: @Youssef.Z I reproduced simple application and its behavior with small changes in the code. And it's surprising to me, that continuous background update even works while your app is terminated. I'm not sure if it even can pass Apple Review because it's so called violation of Apple's rules. Probably I would need some time to look, how it works with the time, as you said after 20-30 minutes.

Comment: @Youssef.Z shared code in answer, that was added or changed in yours.

Comment: Have you enabled background operation for location in the capabilities section?

Comment: @Sander i did a small update on my code above, now i check for the accuracy only for the first location (should be < 70) and i tested my code today. it's working fine in background the only issue is my location jump over +400m sometimes when i'm still at home without move.
Do you an idea what should i do to avoid this bug ?

Comment: @Youssef.Z What device do you use for testing, do you use 3g or wifi internet? Probable explanation is that, iPhone decreases power for GPS hardware while it is not used actively. Also, you can collect all locations during a minute, and then choose the most accurate, however it lead to more battery drain. Probably, they this accuracy is one of those factors, you can't influence

Comment: I have iphone 6s and i tried both with 4g and with wifi same problem, i already used your suggestion but it drain a lot of battery.

Comment: For example now i'm at home and using wifi, look the data i added on the main post

Comment: "distance" - means distance from your actual location?

Comment: and could you add some data while your app is in foreground, just to compare with normal foreground mode

Comment: yes from my home address, and data are same for foreground mode no difference.

Comment: Obviously, it is a limitations due to hardware. And you reached max that you can for the application. If you set maximum accuracy in the foreground and get the same result it means that you could do nothing to improve location accuracy farther. Thanks for discussion.